# How can I use a binary tree to compute a square root?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, data-structures

I want to compute the square root of a number by using a binary tree.

The thought process was to have a start point and the insert function would call the divide function when wanting to place in a node to either the left or the the right.

In my thought process I wanted the divide function to keep dividing until the number is divided evenly and it would return a value. If the number did not get divided evenly when the dividend hits 9, then it would just return the starting number.

I wanted the divide function to also return the dividend and that would go into the right side of the tree. The code I have submitted was supposed to output 4 2 and ['4','2']

I don't get any errors running the code, but when I run the code it's the output isn't lower then the initial starting number

Also this is my first time posting to StackOverFlow, I am a new programmer trying to learn data structures and algorithms. My logic is flawed so if I could get some tips that would be amazing. Thank you for you help!

```
class Square:
    def __init__(self, start, dividend = 2):
        self.start = start
        self.right = None
        self.left = None
        self.num = self.start
        self.value = None
        self.dividend = dividend
    
    def divide(self, num):
        self.num = num
        if self.num % self.dividend == 0:
            return self.num / self.dividend
        if self.dividend == 9:
            return self.num
        self.divide(num)
        return self.dividend+1
    
    
    def insert(self, num):
        _noDivide = 3
        _divide = 4
        if self.start >= _noDivide:
            self.value = self.divide(self.start)
            if self.value == self.start:
                if self.right is None:
                    self.right = Square(self.num)
                else:
                    self.right.insert(self.num)
            elif self.value >= _divide:
                if self.left is None:
                    self.left = Square(self.num)
                else:
                    self.left.insert(self.num)
        else:
            self.num = num   
 
    def PrintTree(self):
        if self.left:
            self.left.PrintTree()
        print(self.num),
        if self.right:
            self.right.PrintTree()   

    def inorderTraversal(self, root):
        res = []
        if root:
            res = self.inorderTraversal(root.left)
            res.append(root.num)
            res = res + self.inorderTraversal(root.right)
        return res


def main():
    root = Square(8)
    root.insert(root.start)
    root.PrintTree()
    root.inorderTraversal(root)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Re: "I want to compute the square root of a number by using a binary tree": Could you elaborate on this a bit more? What exactly does this mean, and why do you want to do it this way?

Comment: Note that you can use binary *search* to approximate a square root; but this doesn't normally involve a binary *tree*, and I don't think it would benefit from adding one.

Comment: @ruakh With this program I wanted to get the exact square root, so if you would input 8 you would get 2|2, or if you would do 20 the output would be 2|5. The "|" would represent the square root symbol.

Comment: Interesting! How would a binary tree help with that, though? Like -- what's actually *in* the tree?

Comment: @ruakh The binary tree is not needed, but I wanted to see if I could implement one for finding the exact square root. I have followed some tutorials, and you could kind of tell due to the names of the functions I used such as "insert". The tree is going to hold quotient values and dividend values. More specifically, the left side would hold the quotient and the right side would hold the dividend values. I would make an interesting project to work on to show my professor and something to put on my portfolio. I just need to work on my algorithm skills.

Comment: Re: "More specifically, the left side would hold the quotient and the right side would hold the dividend values": A binary tree doesn't really have a "left side" and a "right side". Each node in a binary tree has a left child and a right child, each of which is the root of a binary subtree. It doesn't make sense to give a different meaning to different parts of a binary tree.

Comment: Re: "I would make an interesting project to work on to show my professor and something to put on my portfolio": I could be wrong, but I don't think anyone will be interested in a project that doesn't make sense. If a binary tree doesn't help you solve the problem, then why is it there?

Comment: @ruakh I am almost done with my implementation, is there anyway I could send you the code to have you check it out. The way implementing the tree is a way unnecessary, but I want to see if it can be done. I am also building out my own queue system to handle the data from the tree. Once I finish it you will see. It's impractical but interesting at the same time and that's why I want it on my portfolio. Plus coding this out has taught me a lot about Binary Trees and different data structures, so it's a win regardless.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want an *exact surd form*. Prime factorization will do. But to be fancy, here it is:

I'm not sure what do you mean by "the insert function would call the divide function when wanting to place in a node to either the left or the the right". But here is my implementation:

The dividend takes the `left` and the quotient takes the `right`. Always call `divide` on the `right`. Follow the prime factorization algorithm for `divide`. As a result, the product of all `left` in the binary tree is the prime factorization of the number. (Yeah so really does not require a binary tree.) The prime factorization can be easily converted to an *exact surd form*.